# How to find out the average speed, while the speed value is generating per second

Tags: android

I have a code which displays the value of current speed by using GPS system. The speed value is changed every second, now i want to generate the average value of the speed. I have a code which is generating the value of average speed with reference to time, instead i want to display my average speed values with reference to distance covered as avg speed = distance covered in total time. My code is as below:

```
private void actualizeTextField() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        if (count > 0) {
            float timeOver = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            tf.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(pointAverage * 3.6
                    / (timeOver / 1000))));

        } else {
            tf.setText("0");
        }

    }
```

how can i generate the accurate values of average speed.

Comment: That more like a math or general programming question than an Android question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I exactly understand your problem, but isn't what you're looking for just "pace" instead of "speed"? Speed has given formula and it's always referenced to time (distance/time) - covered distance in certain time. You can always just flip the fraction to get pace (time/distance) - used time to cover certain distance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is either, but if you want to calculate the average speed you can calculate the speed over X frames (your choice) and then take the average like this:

```
/* Some code */

frame++;
speed += currentSpeed;

if (frame == x) //change 'x' to how often you want average speed to be calculated
{
    averageSpeed = speed /x;
    speed = 0;
    frame = 0;
}

/* Rest of code */
```

Variables are self-explained, feel free to alter between `int` or `float` or anything else.